# SQL function to change number to their string equivalent in varchar2 e.g. 1 '1 ottershaw road' to 'one otthershaw road'

Tags: sql

I have string with numbers such as '1 OTTHERSHAW ROAD' I want the the numeral at the start of the string to be converted to textual version so that would be one in the example, so the end results i would like for it to be is'One Otthershaw road'
obviously other lines would have different numbers at the start some going up to hundreds.

Does any one know if there is some sort of sql function that would help me out by converting the number to the string equivalent?

the maximum number i have is like 256.

Comment: what would you do for `153217 Main St`? Seems silly to do anything but a number here.

Comment: Even leaving aside correctly parsing a number into its English word equivalent, you will need something like regular expressions to get the value at the beginning of the address. Support varies between DBMS so we need to know if you are using MySQL, SqlServer, PostgreSQL, etc...